# Wix Driver Installation Debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I'm trying to port a driver installation to Wix, but it keeps failing to install one of the drivers. I am using the difxapi extension, but don't know how to enable logging to get any error messages.

Is there something I can do to find out what is going wrong?

This is the code I'm using; `mlusb.inf` is dependent on `windrvr6.sys`. If remove `mlusb.inf`, the first part installs perfectly fine.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="MainDriverGroup" Directory="DriversFolder">
  <Component Win64="no" Id="MainDriver" Guid="{04604482-1DA8-4E8E-B2BA-108E759F2D99}">
    <difx:Driver Legacy='yes' ForceInstall='yes' Sequence='1'/>
    <File Id='DriverINF' Vital="yes" Source="Files\windrvr6.inf" KeyPath="yes"/>
    <File Id="DriverSYS" Vital="yes" Source="Files\windrvr6.sys"/>
    <File Id="DriverCAT" Vital="yes" Source="Files\wd1021.cat"/> 
  </Component>

  <Component Win64="no" Id="USBDriver" Guid="{63C42BC9-CE54-4C78-A0A1-224533986F45}">
    <difx:Driver Legacy='yes'  ForceInstall='yes' Sequence='2'/>
    <File Id='DriverUSBINF'   Source="Files\mlusb.inf" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>    
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Msiexec (command-line options)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Here is an example command line to enable verbose logging:

```
msiexec /i example.msi /l*v c:\logfile.txt
```

This will create `c:\logfile.txt`, so make sure you have enough permissions to write to `c:\`.